# How to switch between two maps with a click Google Maps API V3?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with two markers one very far from another, in order not to have zoom too far I need to make a page for the maps in full size and I want to dynamically change between the maps so that user don't have to change to an extra window to see the other location. Here is an image of how I want to do this. I really appreciate the help and experience of all.

Here is the js code.

```
(function() {

window.onload = function() {

    // Creating a new map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.2000, -84.4000),
      disableDefaultUI: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


    // Creating the JSON data
    var json = [
        {
            "title": "map 1",
            "lat": 9.93379260367826,
            "lng": -84.22572178326419,
            "description": "<br><br><strong>map 1</strong>Description<br><br>"
        },
        {
            "title": "map 2",
            "lat": 10.575049399803566,
            "lng": -85.58282425643927,
            "description": "<br><br><strong>map 2</strong>Description<br><br>"
        },
    ]

    // Creating a global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Looping through the JSON data
    for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
        var data = json[i],
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
            icon: 'style/images/mapMarker.png'
        });



        // Creating a closure to retain the correct data, notice how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
        (function(marker, data) {

            // Attaching a click event to the current marker
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });


        })(marker, data);

    }

}
    })();
```

[image: Two maps in full window size change to each other on click.]

Comment: The code you posted does not attempt to do what your question describes. Please post code that is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have two tabs or links, which when clicked call a javascript function that simply does `map.setCenter();` with the coordinates for marker 1 or marker 2 as appropriate.

Comment: ^ This would be the easiest way to accomplish this if you don't need to style the maps differently.  Have a read through the [Custom Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) section of the docs.